# counterexample for ill posedness of the laplace equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-functions

Consider the wave equation with initial data:

$$u_{tt}(t,x) + u_{xx}(t,x) = 0$$
$$u(0,x) = u_0(x)$$
$$u_t(0,x) = u_1(x)$$

Hadamard showed that this problem is *ill-posed*: there exist large solutions with arbitrarily small initial data. For instance, if we take $u(t,x) = a_{\omega} \sinh(\omega t) \sin(\omega x)$, then $u_0(x) = 0$ and $u_1(x) = a_{\omega} \omega \sin (\omega x)$, then we can make $u(t,x)$ grow arbitrarily fast while keeping $u_0$ and $u_1$ small.

Tweaking this construction, it is not hard to see that for any given $k$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can construct initial data such that

$$
||u_0||_{\infty} + ||u_0^{(1)}||_{\infty} + \ldots + ||u_0^{(k)}||_{\infty} + ||u_1||_{\infty} + ||u_1^{(1)}||_{\infty} + \ldots + ||u_1^{(k)}||_{\infty} < \epsilon
$$

and $||u(\epsilon,x)||_{\infty}  > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. This can be interpreted as saying that the problem is ill-posed even in a Holder sense.

My question is: can one construct an example of a solution $u(t,x)$ with initial data $u_0(x)$ and $u_1(x)$ such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} ||u_0^{(i)}||_{\infty} + ||u_1^{(i)}||_{\infty} < \epsilon$$

while $||u(\epsilon,x)||_{\infty}  > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$? This is exercise 26 in http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f11/downloads/notes2.pdf, which suggests that it should be possible. An explicit construction may be difficult, in which case I would be happy with an abstract argument for existence.

Comment: $u(t,x) = a_{\omega} \sinh(\omega t) \sin(\omega x)$ seems to solve $u_{tt}+u_{xx}=0$ rather than $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$

Comment: Thanks for the correction, the former is the wave equation.

Comment: well, I wouldn't call it "wave" equation (wave equation is really $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$)

Comment: "Laplace's equation" would be most accurate.

Comment: Note that the condition you wrote down is strictly stronger than the condition given in the exercise you linked to. In the case you wrote the higher derivatives are expected to **decay**, which would make your question much, much harder, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes it's stronger. Do you see a way to do it with each derivative being bounded? I don't see how to do either version, so I can't tell if it's much harder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am somewhat doubtful of the claim. Here's why. Let us suppose the **weaker** inequality that for any $k$

$$ |\partial_x^k u_0| < \epsilon, |\partial_x^k u_1| < \epsilon. $$

Now, let us consider a solution $u$ to the Laplace equation with indicated boundary values. We have that along $t = 0$

$$ |\partial_x^k u| < \epsilon, |\partial_x^k \partial_t u| < \epsilon. $$

Using the equation we have

$$ |\partial_x^k \partial_t^2 u| = |\partial_x^{k+2} u| < \epsilon. $$

And by induction

$$ |\partial_x^k \partial_t^{2l} u| = |\partial_x^{k+2l} u| < \epsilon. $$

and

$$ |\partial_x^k \partial_t^{2l+1} u| = |\partial_x^{k+2l} \partial_t u| < \epsilon. $$

This implies that **every single derivative, spatial or temporal** is bounded by $\epsilon$. The practical implication of this is: let

$$ a_{kl} = \partial_x^k \partial_t^l u(0,0) $$

The formal power series

$$ U(t,x) = \sum_{k,l = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!l!} a_{kl} x^k t^l $$

has infinite radius of convergence; the function that it defines is a solution, so we can identify $U$ with $u$.

Now, if you look at $t = \epsilon, x = 0$ of the power series, you see that you have the sum

$$ U(\epsilon,0) = \sum_{l = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{l!} a_{0l} \epsilon^l$$

which we can bound pretty trivially by

$$ (\sup_l |a_{0l}|) \exp(\epsilon) < 2 \epsilon $$

The above argument is clearly independent of where we do the Taylor series: instead of taking the series relative to the origin, we do it relative to $(0,x_0)$ and this tells us that the desired inequality is very far from being true.

---

The above is basically a **quantitative** version of the theorem of [Cauchy-Kowalevski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Kovalevskaya_theorem), and which can be easily extended to initial data in [Gevrey classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevrey_class); we are using here that if a smooth function is such that all its derivatives are bounded by a fixed constant, the function must be real analytic.